# What rule should I add to Firestore DB for not override the existing data in the same array if it has the same value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I add the same data inside the same array in Firestore, it not creates more indexes in the array because it has the same data.

I want it to create more indexed when the same data is entered inside the array.

**for example:**

[image]

**expected result:**

[image: expected result]

code:

```
// collection reference
const collectionRef = collection(db, 'exercises data');
// submit function to add the exercises data
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const usr = auth.currentUser;
    await setDoc(doc(collectionRef, usr.uid), {
        exercise: arrayUnion(exercise),
        sets: arrayUnion(Number(sets)),
        reps: arrayUnion(Number(reps)),
    }, { merge: true })
}
```

Comment: `arrayUnion()` adds data only if it is not present in the array already. If you want to add duplicate values then you'll have to read, modify and update the entire array back as in the linked answers.